# Alternative to OpenERP?

Tags: linux, open-source, odoo

Is there an alternative for OpenERP that is also open source?

Comment: Why is there a need of any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out openbravo

http://www.openbravo.com/

Comment: thanks a ton man for your quick reply if any one come cross any other tool pls let us know thanks

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia has a [list of ERP software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ERP_software_packages) that shows the licence model. I think [Tryton](http://www.tryton.org/en/) is the one that I've seen discussed the most in the OpenERP forum.

Answer (score -1):

There's also [Stoq](http://www.stoq.com.br/), a free brazilian ERP: